# Systemd startup script for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: autostart

I'd like to write a simple (systemd I guess) start up script that just does the following:

1. Issues the command of `/opt/ibm/domino/notes/90010/linux/server -jc -c`.
2. From the directory of `/srv/notesdata`.
3. In the username of "notes".
4. Thus starting a background process.

It doesn't need to be any fancier than that.

(If I do the above myself manually, it works fine.)

Here's my latest attempt; the failure message was "signal." Any help would be appreciated. Happy to strip any variables out of what's below to make it even simpler. Simple is good here, not a production box here, just a test one.

```
[Unit]
Description=Domino
After=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=notes
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/srv/notesdata
ExecStart=/opt/ibm/domino/notes/90010/linux/server -jc -c
TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```